# How to generate multiple list from combinations between some elements of list of lists (in java or C)

Tags: list, combinations

I work with a proprietary language, it's similar to java or C.
I have a collection of elements, some of them are collections too. I want to generate variations of the general collection, but I dont know how to do this.

I just need a general explanation of the algorithm, i think in some languages like python this could be very easy with iteration tools, but i have to implement the solution manually. I think maybe i have to use recursion but im not sure. I expect to have no more than 4 or 5 embedded lists each of them with 3 or 4 elements so I dont think I would have a memory problem.

input:

```
{ [NP, NP_pl] , [NP, NP_pl] , VPa, VPa, Sa, [S, S_nm, S_ws] }
```

expected outputs:

```
{ NP, NP, VPa, VPa, Sa, S}
{ NP, NP, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_nm}
{ NP, NP, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_ws}

{ NP_pl, NP, VPa, VPa, Sa, S}
{ NP_pl, NP, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_nm}
{ NP_pl, NP, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_ws}

{ NP, NP_pl, VPa, VPa, Sa, S}
{ NP, NP_pl, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_nm}
{ NP, NP_pl, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_ws}

{ NP_pl, NP_pl, VPa, VPa, Sa, S}
{ NP_pl, NP_pl, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_nm}
{ NP_pl, NP_pl, VPa, VPa, Sa, S_ws}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a page with implementations in many languages: [Cartesian Product](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_two_or_more_lists). One of them might be even closer to that proprietary language.

And yes, you need recursion (it's just much simpler with recursion).